# CakePHP 3 : $this->set no response data after POST

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, cakephp

I am trying to get a response from my controller into my view files but I'm always just getting no response. I know the controller is getting the right data and the data is in the controller because I used echo to check but then that creates the error unable to emit headers. But when I'm using $this->set I just get no response. I've followed many other questions and added the request handler and tried various things but cannot get this to work.

This is my view file blah.ctp.

```
<?php use Cake\Routing\Router; ?>
<?= $this->Form->create(Null, ['type' => 'POST']) ?>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('customer_id', ['options' => $customers, 'empty' => true,'id'=>'customers']);
?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>

<script>
document.getElementById('customers').addEventListener('change',function(){
   var id = this.value;
    var csrfToken = $('[name=_csrfToken]').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '<?php echo Router::url(array("controller" => "Customers", "action" => "fill")); ?>',
        headers: {          
       Accept: "application/json"  
            },     
        data: {'id' : id},
        beforeSend: function(xhr){
           xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', csrfToken);
        },
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

This is my fill fucntion in CustomersController

```
public function fill(){
        $layout = 'ajax';
        $this->autoRender = false;
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $id = $this->request->data['id'];
            $data = $this->Customers->get($id);
            $this->set(compact('data'));
            $this->set('_serialize', ['data']);
        }  
    }
```

The no response and preview
[image]

Comment: try 'use Cake\Core\Configure;' inside controller

Comment: and change '$this->request->is('post')' to '$this->request->is('ajax')'

Comment: @danny3b still nothing sadly.

Comment: Instead of using set did you try to use echo json_encode($data); exit(); ?

Comment: I had tried echo json_encode($data); but that cause unable to emit headers but by adding exit(); that fixed that and now it works! Thank you so much @danny3b

Comment: Have you tried setting the action to `fill.json` insteado of `fill`?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function fill(){
    $layout = 'ajax';
    $this->autoRender = false;
    if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
        $id = $this->request->data['id'];
        $data = $this->Customers->get($id);
        $this->response->body($data);
    }
}
```